# passing a parameter with file in argument in terminal

Tags: python, parameters, terminal

I'm starting in python and I have to insert a text file as a parameter into an argument from a python script via terminal. How do I do this without generating the following error:[Erro2] No such file or directory? I have already tried using only the name and with the directory. Someone has an example that works?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There's no way to tell what you're doing wrong, so you need to provide more information (including _relevant_ code). Please see the help section for how to ask successful questions.

Comment: Need some more info